# Manage Role users in velocity

Tags: liferay, velocity

I want to manage the users role in my theme velocity template:

```
#set ($foundUser = $cmsuser.getUserByUserId($session.getAttribute("user_id")))

#if($foundUser)
    #if($cmsuser.isUserRole($foundUser, "user_admin"))

        <a href="/group/xxx/xxx" ></a>

    #else
        <a href="/group/xxx/yyy" ></a>
    #end
```

But it doesn't work!!!!

Comment: Whats not working? Are you getting any errors? Do you want to check if the User has that role or permission and accordingly show the link? and what is `isUserRole`? it would help if you can elaborate on the requirement

Comment: I wanto that the user with one role goes to a page A and others in page B.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there are 2 Roles (`RoleU1` and `RoleU2`), so now if I understand correctly if a user has `RoleU1` he have a link to go to a page, say `Welcome Role U1 page`
and the Users with `RoleU2` will have a link to page, `Welcome to Role U2 page`, to do this it you can do the following:

1. Fetch the roles `RoleU1` and `RoleU2` or fetch just their Ids.
2. Fetch the logged-in User.
3. Fetch all the roles of the logged-in User or fetch all the roleIds of the User.
4. Check what role the User has and then accordingly show user the link.

Here is the code for the above steps:

```
#* Fetch the RoleLocalService to fetch the roles, this is similar to using RoleLocalServiceUtil in our custom code in portlets *#
#set($roleLocalService = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.RoleLocalService"))

#* fetch the RoleU1 *#
#set($role_u1 = $roleLocalService.getRole($company_id, "RoleU1"))
#set($role_u1_id = $role_u1.getRoleId())

#* fetch the RoleU2 *#
#set($role_u2 = $roleLocalService.getRole($company_id, "RoleU2"))
#set($role_u2_id = $role_u2.getRoleId())

#* current logged-in User is already defined in the theme as $user, so fetch roles for this user *#
#set ($user_role_ids = $user.getRoleIds())

#* check by looping through the user roles *#
#set ($has_role_u1 = false)
#set ($has_role_u2 = false)

#foreach($user_role_id in $user_role_ids)

    #if($user_role_id == $role_u1_id)
        #set ($has_role_u1 = true)
    #end

    #if($user_role_id == $role_u2_id)
        #set ($has_role_u2 = true)
    #end

#end

#if($has_role_u1)
    <a href="/group/xxx/xxx" >Welcome to Role U1 page</a>
#else if($has_role_u2)
    <a href="/group/xxx/yyy" >Welcome to Role U2 page</a>
#end
```

Hope this is what you required, or atleast will give an hint.